# Apache Camel REST Service - Spring MVC(war) + Tomcat

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I am trying to develop a rest service using apache camel + spring and deploy the war on tomcat.

I dont want to use CXF Servlet.

I tried a few tutorial and can't get it working.

Is this a valid use case? Please provide some inputs as this is the first time i am working on Apache Camel though i have developed services using @ResponseBody earlier.

Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? We need a little more information on what you have tried and what you are experiencing.

Comment: http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/12/basic-rest-service-in-apache-cxf-vs.html

and got 

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot find any registered HttpDestinationFactory from the Bus.

also mine is a spring web app deployed on tomcat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188478/apache-camel-spring-war-tomcat-rest

I have created a new question with code and configs.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, you need to put cxf-rt-http-jetty jar into the war file.

Comment: Bloody well spotted if that is the case.