# Apache Camel + Spring (war) + Tomcat + REST

Tags: rest, tomcat, spring-mvc, apache-camel, cxfrs

I am trying to develp a rest service using apache camel. My project is a spring mvc war deployed on tomcat.

I dont want to use apache cxf (cxf servlet).

```
        public class SampleRouter extends RouteBuilder {

            @override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("cxfrs://http://localhost:1234/sample")
                .process (new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("test");
                    }
                })).setBody(constant("SUCCESS"));
            }
        }


        @Path("/sample")
        public class SampleResource {

            @GET
            public void test() {

            }
        }
```

web.xml has dispatcherservlet, contextloaderlistener.

dispatcher-servlet.xml has mvc:annotation-drivem, context:component-scan,

```
        <camelContext id="server" trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
            <contextScan />
        </camelContext>
```

pom.xml has camel-core, camel-cxf, camel-stream, cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty, cxf-rs-frontend-jaxrs, camel-spring, spring-webmvc, spring-web, spring-context.

Tomcat runs on 8080, there seems to be no exception when server comes up. But, I tried hitting the url (`http://localhost:1234/sample`), nothing seems to be happening.

What am i missing? I would eventually extend this to REST to Spring DSL or REST to Java DSL with authentication, filters and interceptors.

I also tried cxf:rsServer and referred that in router class.

Also, in the future if i have to use https instead of http? or how do i have the url not hard-coded?

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late, but to consume HTTP requests, one may use Apache Camel Servlet component

http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the resourceClass option on the cxfrs endpoint.  Here is an example

```
from("cxfrs://http://localhost:1234/sample?resourceClasses=my.pachage.SampleResource")
```

You can find some example in [camel-cxfrs component page](https://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html).

If you want to export a CXF service through servlet transport, you need to do some work as [it](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) said.

If you want to change the address dynamically, you can take look at the [camel properties component.](http://camel.apache.org/properties)

Comment: As i said, I am not using CXF Servlet or Camel Servlet. Also, I am deploying on Tomcat. The port i configured in cxf:rsServer xml config is 123 whereas tomcat runs on 8080.

I just want to confirm if deployment on tomcat is possible without using the servlets. Also, I am not sure why i need to configure different port for the service than the server and how it will work. Also why do i need to include cxf-jetty jar though i am using tomcat.

Comment: Can i get some help, please??

Comment: It is possible to publish the webserivce without using the servlet transport. In this case you just need to make sure cxf-rt-http-jetty jar is in your class path.

Comment: I tried all possible combinations without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to start a camel route by a consuming cxf rest service which uses the servlet transport then you need to :

1. Clean up your pom.xml and remove any references to jetty.
2. Add the CXF servlet to your web.xml

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <!-- all our webservices are mapped under this URI pattern -->
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
3. Add the servlet-transport dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
       <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
       <version>${cxf-version}</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
4. In your spring/camel configuration

   ```
   <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
   <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

   <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="/restService"
    serviceClass="com.something.test.SimpleServiceImpl"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20" />
   ```
5. Build a route from this consumer endpoint as:

   ```
   from("cxfrs:bean:rsServer?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer")
       .to("log:TEST?showAll=true")
   ```
6. You can now view/(invoke with a method) the endpoint using : `http://host:port/context/services/restService?_wadl`

Comment: As I mentioned I don't want to use CXFServlet or CamelServlet and looking to deploy the war on tomcat.